# Error: rxfire Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot<T>' requires 1 type argument(s) in angular build after npm install

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

I'm getting a new error in Angular after a maintenance npm upgrade where no direct dependency versions changed.

ng serve produces this error and the build fails:

```
[ng]
[ng] Error: node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts:8:29 - error TS2314: Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
[ng]
[ng]  8 export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]  9     count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 10 }, any, DocumentData>;
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] × Failed to compile.
```

How can I fix this?

I already reinstalled the full project from scratch. Package dependencies match angular fire instructions:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^15.2.2",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 15):

I resolved this issue by force installing rxfire version 6.0.3

```
npm install rxfire@6.0.3
```

I had to restart ng serve as well.

Comment: I also had to add babel: `npm install @babel/runtime --save`

Comment: worked for me. THe problem happened on rxfire version 6.0.5

Answer (score 12):

I have this error and have angular/fire installed using ng add @angular/fire

package.json:

```
"@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
```

package.lock.json:

```
"firebase": "^9.8.0",
"rxfire": "^6.0.0",
```

In node_modules>rxfire>firestore>lite>interface.d.ts

I changed

```
export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
    count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
}, any, DocumentData>;
```

to

```
export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
    count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
}>;
```

Since the error says it need 1 type of argument, I just leave one.

I don't know if it can affect the app, but I don't plan on using Firestore lite.

Answer (score 9):

Install the latest version of firebase:

```
npm install firebase@latest
```

Comment: This worked and seems like the best solution, but why should we have to do this? Isn't the "official" method doing "ng add @angular/fire"? Shouldn't they be checking to make sure this works with new versions of firebase? I just don't understand because Angular and Firebase are both Google products. How are there conflicts like this all the time?

Comment: This fixed it, but we shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: This works for me. I got the following message after running it.

added 23 packages, removed 10 packages, changed 14 packages, and audited 1426 packages in 35s

And this is in a brand new install. Seems odd.

Answer (score 5):

My project does have `"@angular/fire": "7.6.1"` as dependency, and not `firebase` like the OP.

But in this case, it think it will solve both, as i exactly get the same error from the same origin (`node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts`)

Downgrading rxfire to version 6.0.4 did not work for me. Downgrading to version 6.0.3 results in a new error, stating

> '__spreadArray' was not found in 'tslib'

**So there have been two steps to solve** (for me):

1. Overwrite Firebase or @angular/fire module resolution to rxfire in `package.json` to 6.0.3. I added the way for pnpm as well, if you use this. Remember to replace `@angular/fire` to `firebase`, depending on need.  Re-install everything afterwards with `npm i`.

   ```
   "pnpm": {
       "overrides": {
           "@angular/fire>rxfire": "6.0.3"
       }
   },
   "overrides": {
       "@angular/fire": {
           "rxfire": "6.0.3"
       }
   }
   ```
2. As said, the original error is gone, but there are complaints that some parameters cannot be found in `tslib`. Surprisingly, I read a lot about updating tslib to the latest version, but that didn't work. What does work is installing v2.1.0, specifically. Use `--save-exact` to avoid a version greater than 2.1.0.

   ```
   npm i --save-exact tslib@2.1.0
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using `rxfire@6.0.5`, but issue was fixed when i manually installed the specific version `rxfire@6.0.4`

I took these steps:

1. Deleted `rxfire` from my `node_modules` folder
2. Manually installed the specific version: `npm i rxfire@6.0.4`
3. Built the app: `npm run build`

Comment: This worked for me when using in a Angular v16.2.0 standalone app with    `@angular/fire@7.6.1`

Comment: @AlDass Can i ask what you did?

Comment: @AaronNebbs I've updated my answer with more detailed steps. 1) deleted `rxfire` from my `node_modules` folder. 2) `npm i rxfire@6.0.4` 3) `npm run build`

Answer (score 2):

I followed some advices in the answers and solved doing this:

- deleting `rxfire` from node_modules
- run `npm i rxfire@6.0.4`
- run `npm update` (cause I had new errors after installing rxfire)

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error following only the minimal install instructions from the [AngularFire repository](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md). So I'm guessing it's a bug. A quick-and-dirty solution if you just want to ignore the issue is to add `skipLibCheck: true` to the `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json file in the root directory. That silenced the error so that the app compiled but of course skipping the lib check can introduce other issues so it's not a production-ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have found this error following the official documentation of @angular/fire, Separating the imports resolved the issue.

```js
import { Firestore, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

I have found the solution from - [Link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3422#issuecomment-1700723241)